# gnome-software manager staying in RAM when closed xUbuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, gnome-software

I'll run `gnome-software` 3.20.1 then close the program. However, the program's process does not close, and takes up a notable chunk of memory. The program will also stall program installation and will interfere with `apt`-related utilities, citing a database lock.

Also,  `apport-bug` will not allow reporting of the program, instead saying:

```
The problem cannot be reported:

This is not an official Ubuntu package. Please remove any third party package and try again.
```

Running `lsb_release -a` returns:

```
LSB Version: core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:core-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:printing-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-amd64:security-9.20160110ubuntu0.2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial
```

`sudo apt-get clean` reports no errors.

Is there a way to configure the program to close properly and remove the database lock? Or, is there a way to report this bug through Apport?

Comment: Have you installed gnome-software?

Answer (score 0):

You should see a little icon in the top left corner or gnome software, click on it and select the Quit option to exit without keeping running in the background.

And yes indeed, gnome 3.20 is not officially supported by Ubuntu yet, looks like you added a third party repository.